# How can i add custom multi option Attribute in sales order grid like select warehouse and able to edit on the grid itself

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, sales-order, table, multiselect-attribute

I need to add custom multi selection option for admin purpose, like the ordered products currently available in which location warehouse. Its display like both inside of the order page and Sales->order-> Grid

```
//custom code
$this->addColumn('warehouse ', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('warehouse'),
    'index'     => 'warehouse',
    'type'      => 'text',
    'width'     => '70px',
    'sortable'  => false,
    'filter'    => false,
     'renderer' => 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productatt',
));
```

But It display only Column Name, how can i display with values,

Output:

[image]

Note: After placing the order the admin manually select the warehouse right after its display inside the object.

Comment: have a look at this

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75315/how-to-add-product-selection-grid-in-admin-form

Comment: @YiorgosMoschovitis My task completely different compare than what you suggested.

Comment: `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Renderer_Productatt` is this file exits ?

Comment: yes, obviously. code : https://snag.gy/ihVdHW.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I've been using BL Custom Grid for years and it will do exactly what you need.

https://github.com/iplaydu/BL_CustomGrid

It provides you with an option to add any custom attribute and even extend the each and every grid to your liking (especially for product grid). If you have some grids already extended then you also have an option to only rewrite the ones you want.

PS. Don't go for the latest version as it doesn't work on some instances, I use 1.9.2.

Comment: I am already tried BL grid, it's also not working,, in that not able to select attribute,, try and you can also know that,,

Comment: What error are you getting? And what version of magento are you using, am using this extension on two websites and works great ;)

Comment: I am using magento ver : 1.9.2.3 and my attribute --> https://snag.gy/31vmES.jpg

Comment: And how can i add attribute using BL Custom Grid ->  https://snag.gy/9uOHKg.jpg

Comment: Could you pls guide me, how can i add my custom attribute on sales order grid?

Comment: If i import BL_CustomGrid by Magento connect manager there is no issue, as you know last month Magento closed Magento connect manager and BL_CustomGrid not available in New Magento Market Place. I just download BL_CustomGrid by GitHub but its not working getting error like,

Comment: a:5:{i:0;s:255:"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'abc_abc.customgrid_grid' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `customgrid_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (`module_name` = 'admin') AND (`controller_name` = 'system_config')";i:1;s:2951:"#0 /home/abc/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)..... How can i solve this error?

Comment: The install of sql didn't run. Make sure that the caching is on, prior to dropping the files into your directories. Once you drop them there, clear the cache with (var/cache).

Comment: Thank You, installed successfully. Could you pls guide me, how can i add my custom attribute on sales order grid? Note : Sales->order->grid

Comment: BL Custom Grid does not have support for custom attributes in the Sales > Orders window